# SQL WildCards and LIKE

Tags: sql, ms-access, wildcard, sql-like

I have table called INFO

```
ID   Name
1    John
2    David
3    Kim
...  ...
...  ...
```

And I want to select Name with first letter **D**

```
SELECT Name FROM INFO
WHERE Name LIKE 'D%';
```

But I don't get any results. Why? What is wrong?

Comment: Seems to be okay. Maybe Name or Info are reserved words. Can you try embedding them in square brackets? `SELECT [Name] FROM [Info] WHERE [Name] LIKE 'D%'`.

Comment: Is it possible that there are blanks in front of the first char?

Comment: access like clauses must be like 'D*' ( it doesnt conform )

Comment: @amdixon Thanks with 'D*' everything work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `*` instead of `%`. see here for [examples](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/queries/like.php).

```
SELECT Name FROM INFO
WHERE Name LIKE 'D*';
```